# ImageList and BltBit - ting

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ce

I am having trouble in CE  BltBit from a previously created compatable hdc to device's hdc.

The following code works:

```
 hdc = pdis->hDC;
 FillRect(hdc, &(pdis->rcItem), (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
 ImageList_Draw(himl, imageIndex, hdc, 15 , 30, ILD_NORMAL);
```

However the following just draws the black rectangle and does not put the image on top.

```
        hdc = pdis->hDC;
        hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        FillRect(hdc, &(pdis->rcItem), (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
        ImageList_Draw(himl, imageIndex, hdcmem, 0 , 0, ILD_NORMAL);
        BitBlt(hdc, 15, 30, 130, 100, hdcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Any ideas most welcome.

Best regards
E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CreateCompatibleDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922550.aspx) doesn't do what you think it does. From the linked page:

> Before an application can use a memory device context for drawing operations, it must select a bitmap of the correct width and height into the device context. This may be done by using [`CreateCompatibleBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922174.aspx) to specify the height, width, and color organization required in the function call.

Device contexts are an abstraction. There must be a storage behind them -- a screen or, in your case, a bitmap.

Comment: Haha.. avakar you are dead right. Thank you. I did think that there was a memory block behind a DC. You have answered some other niggles that I have had in my mind. Thanks again.